# Why will my margin-top CSS not work in this case?

Tags: html, css, margin

I believe that the issue I am having is related to `margin`s not collapsing on a `div` that is inside another `div` but I may be wrong.

I am hoping someone can push me in the right direction on this.

Here is a small snippet of the code from the page I am working on:

```css
.space25 {
  margin-bottom: 1.563em;
}
#menu {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: .9375em;
  margin-bottom: .9375em;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">
  <div id="header">

    <div id="logo">
      <img src="logohuge2.png" width="750px">
    </div>

    <div id="menu">
      <h5><span class="btn">CURRENT WORK</span> <span class="btn-active">PRICING</span> <span class="btn">CONTACT</span></h5>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="mediumtitle" class="25space">
    Basic Packages</br>
    </br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because your class in CSS is different than your class in HTML

you have this:

```
<div id="mediumtitle" class="25space">
```

but then you have in CSS

```css
.space25 {
    margin-bottom: 1.563em;
}
```

### Notes

- A class can't never start with a number
- Don't use `width` html tags, instead use CSS to style `img`
- `</br>` is invalid, the valid should be `<br>` or `<br/>`, but avoid using `<br />` in content, instead use `margin` or `padding` depending oh the case

#### Snippet

```css
.space25 {
  margin-bottom: 1.563em;
}
#menu {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: .9375em;
  margin-bottom: .9375em;
}
img {
  width: 750px
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="//placehold.it/750x300" />
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
      <h5><span class="btn">CURRENT WORK</span> <span class="btn-active">PRICING</span> <span class="btn">CONTACT</span></h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mediumtitle" class="space25">
    Basic Packages
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right. I did have the class swapped. I did change it because I seemed to remember that class names cannot start with numbers. That being said, when I am setting the top margin for the menu DIV, is it pushing the margin against the logo DIV or is it pushing its margin against the top of the view?  I made the changes and it seems to be working. It seems to be in fact pushing against the menu DIV above it.

Comment: That's because you a `h5` which has default `margin`, if you want a `menu`, use the correct semantics for that, using `ul` and `li`

Comment: Ahh  Yes  I guess I should use a list and style that appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

A class name shouldn't start with numerics, see here an explanation of why : https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/6028607

So, with `.space25` instead of `.25space`, it works fine.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j7wn996q/2/)